# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 90), found shape=(None, 2, 90)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can anybody help with the following problem when using Keras predict function the input shape for the prediction dataset seems to be changing (predict seems to add 'none' to the first dimension).

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = MinMaxScaler()

normalized_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
normalized_predict_data = scaler2.fit_transform(predict_dataset)

x = normalized_data[:, 0:90]
y = normalized_data[:, 90]

z = normalized_predict_data[:, 0:90]
print(z.shape)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=90, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.33, epochs=50, batch_size=100, verbose=0)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Model loss: %.2f, Accuracy: %.2f" % ((loss * 100), (accuracy * 100)))

Xnew = z
ynew = model.predict(array([Xnew]))

for item in Xnew:
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (item, ynew[0]))
```

When calling the print function to show the shape of the prediction dataset this prints out (2, 90) as expected (2 rows of data and 90 inputs)

When trying to use the predict function this instead prints the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 90), found shape=(None, 2, 90)
```

Comment: your x_train's shape is = (None, 2,90) and `None` refer to batch. but in your model, you set input shape is (None, 90). you can solve your problem with write like : `model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=(2, 90), activation='relu'))`

Comment: My x_train shape when printed looks correct and not (None, 2, 90). Print shows:

    (304, 90) (76, 90) (304,) (76,)

Comment: OK, but in training, your mdel select multiple x_train with batch_size, None refer to batch_size

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following work for me (my model was trained to take 2D input):

```
X_new = [[-1.0, -1.0]]
model.predict(X_new)
```

or:

```
X_new = [-1.0, -1.0]
model.predict([X_new])
```

Comment: Note that X_new has to be a list, NOT an array! Use the .tolist() function to easily go from an array to a list

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by this code line `ynew = model.predict(array([Xnew]))`.

Please remove the array from this line and use this: `ynew = model.predict(Xnew)`

I have replicated the similar code with an abalone dataset and attached this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/6a613924425ce95359163f0ad5bb89ee/sklearn-gist.ipynb) for your reference.